# Orthogonal function expansions and vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, hilbert-spaces, matrix-equations

Consider a function $f: [-1,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ expanded in terms of Legendre functions:
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n P_n(x)
$$
Is it possible to define vectors with infinitely many elements:
\begin{align}
\mathbf{a} &= \left( a_0, a_1, \dots \right) \\
\mathbf{P}(x) &= \left( P_0(x), P_1(x), \dots \right)
\end{align}
and say
$$
f(x) = \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{P}(x)
$$
?

What about a matrix $\mathbf{P}$ whose columns correspond to $P_0, P_1, \dots$, and whose rows are defined for all $x \in [-1,1]$, so that row "x" of $\mathbf{P}$ would be $\mathbf{P}(x)$. In case could we say
$$
\mathbf{f} = \mathbf{P} \mathbf{a}
$$
where $\mathbf{f}$ is a vector of all uncountably infinitely many $f(x)$ for $x \in [-1,1]$ and we use the normal matrix-vector multiplication above? Is it possible to define such "infinite" vectors and "infinite" matrices and do normal linear algebra operations with them?

Is there a branch of mathematics which studies these sorts of things?

Comment: For your first question; how is that not exactly the power series? The dot product is just a sum so its just different notation for the same thing, unless I'm being very dumb I think the answer to your first question is yes.

Comment: The branch of mathematics : Hilbert space theory : see p. 9 of (http://www.matfys.lth.se/education/FMFF15/HilbertSpace.pdf) that I see you have mentionned in your tags... Besides, working with infinite size matrices might, in some cases, be interesting on the side of intuition, but, usually, isn't a fruitful way to approach such questions.